# Discover version of Outlook (Microsoft Outlook or New Outlook) and Run Code Appropriately

Tags: excel, email, outlook

I have a process in place to copy registration data from worksheet(s) and attach to email and send.  With the new version of Outlook, the code is not working. Our company is not forcing the use of the New Outlook, but many users have adopted.

I have put a Band-Aid on the issue by calling a sub to open Outlook (MS Outlook) and then after mail send close (MS Outlook). Not good for a user that has remained in the Microsoft Outlook version vs. New Outlook as it closes their Outlook at the end of the operation.  I cannot find a solution that discovers the version of Outlook they are working in and executes or does not execute opening the Microsoft Outlook version to send the email.

I have attached three pieces of the code and hoping you can find a better solution for me.

```
Sub Send_Registrations()

Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim tempFile As String
Dim strbodymsg As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim NewFileName As String

ManageCo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Property Info").Cells(4, 3).Value
ManageCoID = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Property Info").Cells(5, 3).Value

strbody = "Dear" & " Team," & vbCrLf
strbody = strbody & "<p>Please create Amadeus Learning Universe (ALU) Logins for the attached list of hotel users."
strbody = strbody & "<p>If you have any questions please do not hesitate to reach out directly." & vbCrLf
strbody = strbody & vbCrLf
strbody = strbody & vbCrLf
strbody = strbody & "<p>Thank you!"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALU_Registration").Copy

Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook

tempWB.SaveAs Filename:="ALU_Registration_User_Names", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
    
    With xEmailObj
        .Display = False
        .To = "hospitality.education@amadeus.com"
        .Cc = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ManageCo & " - " & ManageCoID & " - " & "LMS User Creation - " & Date
        .Attachments.Add tempWB.FullName
        .HTMLBody = strbody
    
    If DisplayEmail = False Then
        .Display
        .Send
        MsgBox ("your ALU Registration List request was successfully sent"), vbSystemModal
    End If

End With

tempWB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
Kill tempWB.FullName
tempWB.Close savechanges:=False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set xEmailObj = Nothing
Set xOutlookObj = Nothing

End Sub

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Sub OpenOutlook()
    Shell ("OUTLOOK")
End Sub

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Sub CloseOutlook()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    objOutlook.Quit
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Your next post could be about closing Outlook if it was not already open.

Comment: fyi `On Error Resume Next` is always inappropriate just before `With xEmailObj`. You doubled down to 200% inappropriate by not having an `On Error Goto 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do with the new Outlook (Monarch). I exposes no externally accessible API besides web (JS) addins.

Keep in mind that the new Outlook is *not* a replacement for the desktop version of Outlook - it is a replacement fro Windows Mail and Windows Calendar.